# Google analytics api returns data in chunks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I make a query to the core reporting api filtered by a specific keyword, it returns the data in chunks. I believe it does this because the query uses an extended time period of a year. This a complete pain since some the data like the `total_value` needs to be summed and `revenue_per_transaction` needs to be averaged.

Is there any way to prevent this "chunking"? If not, what it is the best way to overcome this?

Sample response:

```
{keyword="KEYWORD_A", visits="2", total_value="20192.75", revenue_per_transaction="20192.75", transactions="1", day="31", month="05"},
{keyword="KEYWORD_A", visits="1", total_value="5789.8", revenue_per_transaction="2894.9", transactions="2", day="12", month="07"}
```

Here is my current solution to summing the `total_value` attribute. Since `revenue_per_transaction` needs to be averaged, I figured I'd try to address the root of the problem, the chunked response.

```
sum_keys = [:total_value, :revenue_per_transaction]

    data.group_by{ |h| h[:keyword] }
    .map{ |keyword, related|
      tmp = {keyword: keyword}
      tmp.merge! Hash[sum_keys.zip Array.new(sum_keys.size, 0)]
      related.reduce(tmp) { |summed, h|
        sum_keys.each { |key| summed[key] += h[key].to_f }
        summed
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample response, it looks like you're specifying some time dimensions on the query (`ga.day`, `ga.month`)?

If you leave out the time dimensions, the Core Reporting API should return a summed value over the start/end date.

Have you tried using the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)? It's a great to experiment with different dimensions/metrics to make sure you're getting the data you expect.